# Getting correct address from user typed street address using google maps

Tags: google-maps

I've never used the google-maps api, but I just want to do one particular thing.

I've got around 1000 user typed street addresses. Some are missing states and postcodes. I've noticed if I type these addresses into google maps it generally gives me back the state and postcode (only very rarely it gives some options). Is there a way to do this programatically, so I don't have to manually copy/paste this in? Has someone already made an application/library to do this that I can just feed the user typed data to?

**Edit:**

I've noticed this does the job:

https://maps.google.com.au/maps?q=1%20George%20st%20sydney

It returns state and postcode. But it returns it on a webpage with a whole lot of other stuff. I just want the address only. I guess I could grep through the results, but some additional thing to add to the query string so it only returns the raw address (or some structure) would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Geocoding API - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

E.g. http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=1%20George%20st%20sydney ; you can replace "json" with "xml" if you prefer. Look for "formatted_address" in the result, or individual address components, depending on what you need.

However, I'm quite frustrated that it sometimes doesn't work, even for some cases where the regular google maps search is successful.